# What decimal value does some hexadecimal constant have in Android

Tags: android, constants

> #### Problem

In the following code, what is the decimal value for `0X02`, `0X03`, `0X04`? Are they hexadecimal numbers? Any difference when the X letter is upper case and lower case?

> #### Code

```
public class CertainLibraryClass {
    public class ActivityResultCode {
    public static final int CODE_A = 0X02;
    public static final int CODE_B = 0X03;
    public static final int CODE_C = 0X04;
    }
// ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are hexidecimal numbers.
The case of the x will not make a difference.
You are correct, the methods that are public can be called from outside of the class.

Comment: Thank you @PunDefeated, the `public` or `private` modifier part of the question I've moved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781526/why-are-some-constants-public-and-other-private-in-an-android-library-code, you can move your answer there so that I can vote it.

Comment: That's okay, I don't really want to double dip :)