# Why are some constants public and other private in an Android library code

Tags: android, constants

> #### Problem

Why some constants are under the `public` modifier while some other `private`? Are those under `public` can be called from applications that use the library? If so, how to call the constant from an app, is it like this: `CertainLibraryClass.ActivityResultCode.CODE_A`?

> #### Code

```
public class CertainLibraryClass {
    public class ActivityResultCode {
    public static final int CODE_A = 0X02;
    public static final int CODE_B = 0X03;
    public static final int CODE_C = 0X04;
    }
    public class VersionCode {
        private static final int VERSION_MAJOR = 1;
        private static final int VERSION_MINOR1 = 0;
        private static final int VERSION_MINOR2 = 2;
    }
// ....
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it and answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why some constants are under the `public` modifier?

**Ans:** So that all other classes can access it e.g.`RESULT_OK`,`SUCCESS`.

Why some constants are under the `private` modifier?

**Ans**:So that only that class can access it

e.g. consider you are calling `getId()` libarary function from your class

```
public class CertainLibraryClass {
private static int ID=0;

public static int getId()
{
return ID+1;
}
```

here you are not accessing `ID` field directly ,instead you are calling `getId()` function which ultimately returns the id, it means that `ID` variable is internally used by `CertainLibraryClass` class